# Create a calculated field in tableau

Tags: count, conditional-statements, tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a set of data in the following format:

```
Items Shipped | Month

A          1

B          1

C          1

D          2

E          2

F          3

G          3

H          3
```

I would like to show the count of items shipped each month using a calculated field in Tableau.

```
Item_Count | Month

3 1

2 2

3 3
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably have a look on the Tableau page for their basic tutorials:
https://www.tableau.com/learn/training

- Drag the `[month]` pill to row (if it's an actual date, change it to discrete month, otherwise leave it like it is)
- Drag the `[item_count]` to columns, click on it and change it to COUNT or COUNTD depending whether you want the total count or only the distinct elements.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful